# Find the value of these sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the value of the following series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2}{3^{i-1}}$$

and:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i-1} \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}$$

On both series I stated that they converge. I was researching in some sources and found that for the first one there exists a general formula but I couldn't understand it. For the second one I used the alternating series test but I can't figure the total sum.

Thanks.

Comment: They are [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

The general formula for geometric series provides a nice introduction to proofs. Let $S$ be a series defined below.
$$S = a + a r + a r^2 + a r^3 + \ldots + a r^n$$
Here, $a$ is the initial term and $r$ is the common ratio. Then
$$rS = \color{blue}{ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \ldots + ar^n} + a r^{n+1} = \color{blue}{S - a} + a r^{n+1}$$
Then
$$S(r-1) = -a + a r^{n+1}$$
or $S = a\frac{r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}$. Now expand your first sum to get
$$S = 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{-1} + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{0} + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{1} + \ldots + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{n-1}$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{3}S = 2 + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{1} + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{2} + \ldots + 2 * \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{n}$$
or, by the formula above using $a = 2$ and $r = \frac{1}{3}$,
$$\frac{1}{3}S = 2 \frac{\big( \frac{1}{3}\big)^{n+1} - 1}{\frac{-2}{3}}$$
which means $S = 9-\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^{n-1}$. Expand your second series and see if you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Both the series are [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
The sum of a geometric series containing $n$ terms is calculated using the summing formula:
\begin{equation}
\text{Sum} = \text{($1^{st}$ term)}\frac{(1 - r^n)}{(1 - r)}
\label{sum}
\end{equation}
where, common ratio, $r = \frac{i^{th}~\text{ term}}{(i-1)^{th}~\text{ term}}$. For ease, $r$ can be taken as :  $r = \frac{2^{nd}~\text{ term}}{1^{st}~\text{ term}}$.

The first series can be expanded as:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{2}{3^{i-1}} &= \frac{2}{3^{(0-1)}} + \frac{2}{3^{(1-1)}} + \frac{2}{3^{(2-1)}} + \cdots (n+1)~\text{terms} \\
            &= 6 + 2 + \frac{2}{3} + ... (n+1)~\text{terms} \\       
\end{align}
(Note, both the series have $(n+1)$ terms as the index $i$ runs from $0$ to $n$. )

Here, the $1^{st}$ term is $6$ and $r = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$. Now, applying the summing formula, the sum for the series is:
$$\text{Sum } = 6~\frac{(1 - (\frac{1}{3})^{(n+1)})}{(1 - \frac{1}{3})} = 9~\left(1 - \frac{1}{3^{(n+1)}}\right)$$

Similarly, the second series can be expanded as:
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} \frac{1}{2^{i-1}} &= (-1)^{0-1} \frac{1}{2^{0-1}} + (-1)^{1-1} \frac{1}{2^{1-1}} + (-1)^{2-1} \frac{1}{2^{2-1}} + \cdots (n+1)~\text{terms} \\
&= -2 + 1 + \frac{-1}{2} + \cdots (n+1)~\text{terms}
\end{align}

Here, the $1^{st}$ term is $-2$ and $r = \frac{1}{-2} = -\frac{1}{2}$. Now, applying the summing formula, the sum for the series is:
$$\text{Sum } = (-2)~\frac{(1 - (-\frac{1}{2})^{(n+1)})}{(1 - \frac{-1}{2})} = -\frac{4}{3}~\left(1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(n+1)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

These are [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), where the ratio of one term to the next is constant.

If the first term is $a$ and the ratio of successive terms is $r\ne1$, the sum of the series is given by

$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{n}=a\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

In your first example, $a=6$ and $r=\frac13$; in your second example, $a=-2$ and $r=-\frac12$.